# Smart iterator to iterate over two arrays simultaneously and perform an operation that returns a custom type

Tags: c++, arrays, stl, c++14

I am working in an STL like header-only [DSP library](https://github.com/mohabouje/eDSP). Today I was starting to optimize some functionalities and I had to implement a function that estimates the [SNR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal-to-noise_ratio) of a signal.

If we suppose that we are working with zero-mean signals, the variance equals the power, so the SNR is the ratio of the variances of signal and noise.

[image: SNR formula]

In practice, we do not know the noise signal and it changes constantly in time. Normally, we can approximate the noise as the difference between your clean signal and the recorded one:

[image]

Regarding the code of the library, there is already existing code to estimate the variance, so as a first approach I did something like this:

```
const auto functor = [](const value_type left, const value_type right) {  
    return left - right; 
};

// Allocation of memory, O(N)
std::vector<float> noise(N);
std::transform(std::cbegin(recorded), std::cend(recorded), std::cbegin(signal), std::begin(noise), functor);

const auto var_ref   = statistics::variance(std::cbegin(recorded), std::cend(recorded));
const auto var_noise = statistics::variance(std::cbegin(noise), std::cend(noise));

const auto SNR = converter::pow2db(var_ref / var_noise);
```

This is the list of requirements of the implementation:

- I cannot modify the input data (read-only).
- I cannot use boost or any external library, just standard C++
- I should avoid temporal allocations: `O(1)` space.
- I cannot modify the signature of the variance signal.

The code violates one of them as It allocates memory for the noise signal, `O(N)` space.

I did manage to find a solution,  but I am not pretty sure if it is the most elegant one. Basically, I used the idea of the `zip` function in python, and I created an iterator that iterates over two arrays simultaneously and performs an operation each time you access it (lazy initialization).

This is the code of the iterator:

```
template <class Iter1, class Iter2, class zip_functor>
class zip_iterator {
public:
    using first_type = typename std::iterator_traits<Iter1>::value_type;
    using second_type = typename std::iterator_traits<Iter2>::value_type;
    using iterator_category = std::input_iterator_tag;

    constexpr zip_iterator(Iter1 first1, Iter2 first2, zip_functor&& f) :
        first1_(first1),
        first2_(first2),
        functor_(f) {
    }

    constexpr auto operator !=(const zip_iterator& other) const {
        return this->first1_ != other.first1_ and
               this->first2_ != other.first2_;
    }

    constexpr auto operator ==(const zip_iterator& other) const {
        return this->first1_ == other.first1_ and
               this->first2_ == other.first2_;
    }

    constexpr zip_iterator& operator++() {
        first1_ = std::next(first1_);
        first2_ = std::next(first2_);
        return *this;
    }

    constexpr zip_iterator& operator--() {
        first1_ = std::prev(first1_);
        first2_ = std::prev(first2_);
        return *this;
    }

    constexpr auto operator*() {
        return functor_(*first1_, *first2_);
    }

private:
    Iter1 first1_;
    Iter2 first2_;
    zip_functor functor_;
};
```

Whit the new implementation the code becomes:

```
// Alias of the custom iterator
using first_iter = typename std::array<float, N>::const_iterator;
using second_iter = typename std::array<float, N>::const_iterator;
using zip_iter = zip_iterator<first_iter, second_iter,
        std::function<float(float, float)>>;

// This performs the estimation of the noise in each sample
const auto functor = [](const auto left, const auto right) {
        return left - right;
};

// Estimates the variance of the noise in O(1) space
auto start = zip_iter(std::cbegin(recorded), std::cbegin(signal), functor);
auto end = zip_iter(std::cend(recorded), std::cend(signal), functor);
const auto var_noise = edsp::statistics::variance(start, end);
const auto var_ref = edsp::statistics::variance(std::cbegin(recorded), std::cend(recorded));

const auto SNR = converter::pow2db(var_ref / var_noise);
```

This code fits the requirement and seems to be easy to reuse for other common application in signal processing, but still I am hesitating if this is the most elegant and robust way to do so.

So my question is:

**Is there any more elegant way to solve this problem?  Any reference pattern or idiom that handles this situation?**

Comment: For working code, https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ seems more appropriate.

Comment: You might avoid `std::function` (with a `make_zip_iterator` for example).

Comment: BTW, you currently merge `zip_iterator` with `transform_iterator` (both available in boost or other library, but not in std).

Comment: @Jarod42 thank you for the advice. Regarding the usage of boost, unfortunately I can't use boost or any external libraries.